# Confusion about homogeneity

Tags: st.statistics

This might sound trivial or a simple misunderstanding, but please bear with me as I'm not a Math major.

I want to investigate some aspects of [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) in homogeneous directions and needed simple analytical functions. General solution to the one dimensional wave equation with periodic boundary condition seems reasonable as it's homogeneous and I can use sine and cosine waves in the general form:

$u(x,t)=\sum_i{a_i\sin(f_i(x-ct))+b_i\cos(f_i(x+ct))}$

where $a_i,b_i$ determine amplitudes, $f_i$ represents frequencies and $c$ is the propagation speed.

Now here's my confusion, shouldn't the standard deviation in a homogeneous direction have transitional symmetry? if I use $u(x,t)=sin(3(x-2t))$ this is satisfied, but if I add another term then the std will be a harmonic function of space which is not homogeneous!
I cannot figure out what I'm missing here.

Comment: PCA = Principal Component Analysis https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis

Comment: How did you compute the standard deviation in a omogeneous direction?

Comment: @LucaGhidelli: it's per node: $u^\prime(x)=\int{u(x,t)^2dt}$

Comment: I see, I've mistakenly said it's harmonic function of time which is wrong, it's a harmonic function of space. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after more readings and talking with my friends in Math department, I was confusing homogeneous equations (zero forcing function) and statistical homogeneity. The general solution is valid for homogeneous wave function, but it is not necessarily statistically homogeneous.